# Check marks in Telegram app

Tags: telegram

I show the date and the message I sent with one check mark then I have 2 responses from the user. Shouldn't my message have 2 check marks by it now, if they saw it and responded?

Comment: This sounds like a bug you should report to the devlopers.

Answer (score 0):

Are they using an official Telegram client?

There is telegram clients (for example [Telegram CLI for Linux](https://telegram.org/dl/cli)) that lets you do it, you can reply to a message without marking it read.